# Fill NaN values in a column w/ column average

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

[df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCQR5.png)

I would like to replace the NaN value in the purch_amt column with the column mean. I have the following code:

```
df2= df['purch_amt'].fillna(value= df['purch_amt'].mean()).to_frame()
df2
```

However this is returning only the purch_amt column as a dataframe. Ideally I would like to output the entire dataframe, with the updated purch_amt column.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind I answered my own question. Correct code should be:

```
df['purch_amt'].fillna(value= df['purch_amt'].mean()).to_frame()
df
```

This returns the entire original dataframe, with the puch_amt column mean replacing it's NaN value

Comment: you can use a dictionary in fillna, and avoid recreating a dataframe: ``df.fillna({"purch_amt": df['purch_amt'].mean()})``. You could also just reassign the fillna operation : ``df['purch_amt'] = df['purch_amt'].fillna(df['purch_amt'].mean())``